# Code Signing for AdHoc Beta Testing

Tags: ios, xcode, code-signing-certificate

I have been working this for past two days, and haven't come up with a solution. I have Created  Provision for Distribution in Apple perfectly. I don't know How to Set up Built setting and Code signing process in Xcode 5. Any one who could explain briefly will be appreciated.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/code-signing/

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1

Comment: downvote vandhadhum Q ah thukita pola??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you have created certificate and a distribution profile.

First, download both the profile and certificate from your developer account. Just double click on them and it will get copied to respective locations automatically.

Now open your project settings and under build settings tab look for Code signing section. 
Set the certificate and profile which you have just installed.

[image]

Do the same under Target-> build settings.

Next, you need to set the bundle identifier with which you have created the app id in developer portal. Note down the Bundle ID, version info and set it in Target -> General

[image]

If everything went well archive your code and distribute the **ipa** file which is now code signed.

Refer [here](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2915/ios-code-signing-under-the-hood) for more details.